# Better ways to generate codes in django (python)

Tags: python, django, random, django-rest-framework

I am working on an authentication project where I am applying different features like email verification, password reset and these features rely on emails.

Now i want to send a code to the user through an email and verify that on the backend.

Now to generate the code(5-digit), this is what i did;

```
import random
code = random.randint(10000, 99999)
print(code)
```

I just want to know is this a better way to do so. Are there any drawbacks or just fine.

Comment: It's one line of code.  How could you possibly do better than that?

Comment: Django already has a few built-in email verification helpers. You should use that. The drawback of your approach is you'll need to store this token in the database, whereas Django will create cryptographically signed tokens, which don't need any saving. Those tokens are self-contained, i.e. they will have the verification code cryptographically embedded in them.

Comment: @TimRoberts i didn't meant in terms of shortened  code but the approach to do so.

Comment: @xyres can you please mention some of these.

Comment: Also i don't want verification links to be sent but verification codes

Comment: Sorry, those tokens are long and, so, are sent out in links. So, not what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually that is what made me to do so... I want codes only so that i can send them from the frontend and do direct verification but by links this is not possible... BTW thanks for giving your time

Comment: You can use django-mfa2 as it provides such features https://github.com/mkalioby/django-mfa2

Comment: I started building my own auth system and already created the email verification API. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby after completing my API i am going  to give django-mfa2 a try

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After searching for it, i don't think i need any special code creator but i can use the one mentioned in the question and i can make it more special by adding some special characters in the beginning and the end and maybe with varying number.

I can also keep a count of the requests sent to the route and if that is more than 3(say), just refresh the code, making it a more secure.

One more way is to keep track of the time and delete the code after say 3 minutes.

Another way is to create a new code and delete the older one every time a user provides a wrong code. This seems a good option for me but i think it is a little less efficient as it requires email sending.

Comment: Please leave your suggestions